# How to get object from ASP WebClient response

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the code I have currently:

```
var response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wb.UploadValues("URL", "POST", data));
```

response becomes:

```
"{\n  \"success\": false,\n  \"error-codes\": [\n    \"invalid-input-response\"\n  ]\n}"
```

How can I turn the response into a normal C# object. I mean, I realize that I can parse this string, remove all the \n and then deserialize the JSON but there must be an easier way to understand a WebClient response...

Comment: did you try JSON.Net ?

Comment: Can you expand on that? I don't know what that is.

Comment: see this http://www.newtonsoft.com/json .. its a open source framework available which is very popular.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Try to parse as following...

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
```

Then you can access the properties as following...

```
var success = results.success;
var error-codes = results.error-codes;
```

Comment: added it from NuGet. Getting the following error: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies

Comment: probably, your Newtonsoft.json version is older or incompatible with your project...
Try as following...
In the package manager console write the following command
`update-package Newtonsoft.Json -reinstall`
and from `web.config` remove following lines

`<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>`